# How to execute batch sql using local execution mode in Flink?

Tags: bigdata, apache-flink

As i know that Flink support local execution mode(refer to https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/dataset/local_execution/).

But i want to execute batch sql in flink using local execution CollectionEnvironment to keep consistent with online-serving and offline training-dataset feature engineering.

Could anyone tell me how to use local mode to execute batch sql ?

Answer (score 0):

The DataSet API has been deprecated in Flink, so I would advise you to move to  the Table API/SQL.

Using the Flink SQL client, you can set the execution mode. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/sqlclient

The setting you're looking for is:
`SET 'execution.runtime-mode' = 'batch';`

Comment: Thanks. TableApi/SQL is ok. And How to specify collectionExecutor(CollectionEnvironment) in batch sql?